# Amplitude.js - Live Stream

Tags: html, audio-streaming

I'm trying to use a Live stream audio and following exactly what this tutorial says, but it does not work. [AmplitudeJS for Live Stream HTML5 Audio](https://serversideup.net/amplitudejs-live-stream-html5-audio/) I have a blank page and nothing error shows in console. I perceived one "contradiction", in tutorial, Amplitude was not initialized as documentations says:

> To initialize Amplitude.js, you must call the Amplitude.init() method and pass in an object that contains an array of songs and settings

I looked for the part of documentation that specify how to use Live Stream, but I didn't find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will update that tutorial! To do a live stream, you will have to have a streaming service set up. Then when initializing Amplitude.js, your songs array will have to include one song object with a 'live' flag of 'true'. See: https://521dimensions.com/open-source/amplitudejs/docs#song-objects

An example init, would be like this:

```
Amplitude.init({
  "songs": [
    {
      "name": "Station Name",
      "url": "https://yourstreamingservice.com/something-that-returns-properly-encoded-audio",
      "station_art_url": "/station/art/url.jpg",
      "genre": "country"
      "live": true
    }
  ]
});
```

When the live flag is set to true, pause cuts off the stream so it doesn't save to local memory and it resumes where the actual stream is at not where the user is set to pause.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Grateful for your answer Dan. at this moment, I cannot make the proper tests, but I will give a feedback soon. :)